# Titanium: Notification with download status

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to create a notification that will include a download status, such as the photo below (marked in yellow:

[image: Status bar with download]

Is there a special way of doing these? A code sample would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed is a special way of doing it. Usually these kind of features require a module to be included. This can easily be done by using [Gitt.io](http://gitt.io).

The module in question is `nc.progressnotification`

You can find the module on [Github](https://github.com/azwan082/nc_progress_notification), or through [Gitt.io](http://gitt.io/component/nc.progressnotification).

An example is added to the [app.js file in the example folder](https://github.com/azwan082/nc_progress_notification/blob/master/example/app.js)

Comment: Btw, is this cross platform, or Android only?

Comment: Android only. iOS does not have this functionality. So Titanium wouldn't be able to do it either